# PHP Array of .txt files with regexp

Tags: php, arrays, regex, file, glob

I try to create an array of all .txt files in my directory with PHP. I do the following:

```
$lel = glob('/.*\.txt/');
```

but it doesn't work - the array $lel is empty while there are .txt files in this directory. I checked it in online regexp tester and it seemed to work..

Comment: You're not including a path to the directory, is the script in the same directory?

Comment: Do spend some time reading the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Jay Blanchard - i set the directory with chdir()

Comment: Omg Fred thanks, i lurked glob() manual but didn't realise that the exact problem is solved there, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

`glob()` doesn't use `preg` expression syntax, it uses the simpler `fpath` syntax which is the same as on the command line. So you need to just check for just

```
$lel = glob('*.txt');
```

instead of

```
$lel = glob('/.*\.txt/');
```